# Leaving out the curly braces

Tags: macros

I'm trying to understand how LaTeX works, but I don't understand the following:

```
\dot X
```

and

```
\dot{\mathcal X}
```

work, but

```
\dot \mathcal X
```

does not work. Can anybody explain why?

Comment: TeX cant set a dot on a macro , i.e. `\mathcal`. `\dot` must see a letter/glyph first to operate on, so `\mathcal{X}` has to be expanded first

Comment: @ChristianHupfer but that hides the point that it's all about how macros find their arguments for example `_` rather than `\dot` things are different `$A_ \mathcal X B $` works without error and works as `$A_ {\mathcal{X}} B $`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I formulated it a bit clumsy, perhaps.

Comment: `$\dot\mathcal X$` seems to work with standard classes, but not with `amsmath`, which redefines things.

Comment: This is a good reason why you should *always* type `\dot{X}`, `\mathcal{X}` and so `\dot{\mathcal{X}}`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Macros defined with normal non delimited arguments take a single token or brace group as the argument so

```
\dot X
```

is

```
\dot{X}
```

and

```
\dot{\mathcal X}
```

is

```
\dot{\mathcal{X}}
```

but

```
\dot \mathcal X
```

is

```
\dot{\mathcal} X
```

which is an error as `\mathcal` is expecting an argument but does not see one.

Comment: Thank you, I think I understand now, but since you say "defined with normal non delimited arguments", is there also a way to define dot to take both mathcal and X?

Comment: @pascal - Are you asking how to redefine `\dot` to make it take two arguments?

Comment: @Mico No sorry I am not very clear perhaps, I meant is it possible to redefine `\dot` to interpret `\dot \mathcal X` as `\dot{\mathcal{X}}`.

Comment: @pascal possibly but it would be a bad idea, the syntax rules described above apply to _every_ command defined in tex. The only things that do not follow it exactly are a few tex primitives such as `_` or `\hbox` which have their own argument scanning rules. So unless you plan to redefine the entire TeX language it is best just to leave as is any attempt to change the scanning would be very fragile and bound to be incompatible with several packages

Comment: @pascal my reference to normal non-delimited arguments I just meant to exclude so called delimited arguments where arguments are delimited by other tokens such as `[..]` or `(..,..)` where the rules are similar but different and not really relevant to your question so I excluded them from the discussion.